# React Native Expo looking for node_modules in the wrong place

Tags: react-native, expo

I am refactoring a react-native app into an Expo app.  When I try to import an `<AppContainer/>` from react-navigation, I get the following error:

```
12:00
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/ayunas/Documents/lambda/RecipeShareExpo/navigation/node_modules'
ERROR
12:00
Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

Here is how the `<AppContainer/>` looks like:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Homepage
    }
})


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

No idea why expo is looking for node_modules in my navigation directory, which contains navigation components.

Comment: Can you create pure expo project , add the source and packages if you neef and run

Comment: This is a pure expo project.  I created it using expo init.  and then I'm trying to add an <AppContainer/> to set up react-navigation.  as soon as I import the AppContainer, expo tries to look for node_modules in the navigation directory

Comment: Do you installed react-navigation? and which version fo the Expo you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to properly import createAppContainer:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

If this does not help, try to delete file "package-lock.json" and folder "node_modules" and run from the project folder `npm install` and `npm install react-navigation --save`